# Setting value on TextField input text become non editable

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a form for updating the data from mongodb I was able to fetch the data and added onchange if the currentId exist then all the data will populate on the form but, my problem is I cannot edit or I cannot type anything on the input to edit the value. I really need your eyes to see something that have missed or missed up. Thanks in advance y'all.

*Profile container*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect }  from 'react';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { getProfile } from '../../../actions/profile'; //fetch method
import Profile from './Profile';

function Index() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts);
    const currentId = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProfile()); 
    }, [currentId, dispatch]);

  return (
        <div className="custom-container">
        {posts.map((profile) => (
            <div key={profile._id}>
                <Profile profile={profile} currentId={currentId} />
            </div>
        
        ))}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Index;
```

*Profile form component*

```
import './Profile.css';
import { React, useState, useEffect }  from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import { TextField  } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { updateProfile } from '../../../actions/profile';

 const Profile = ({ profile, currentId }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    currentId = profile._id;
    const [postData, setPostData] = useState(
        {
            profile: {
                name: "",
                description: "",
                email: "",
                number: "",
            }
                
        }
    );

    const post = useSelector((state) => currentId ? state.posts.find((p) => p._id === currentId) : null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(post) setPostData(post);
    }, [post])

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(currentId) {
            dispatch(updateProfile(currentId, postData));
        }
    }

    // const [ImageFileName, setImageFileName] = useState("Upload Profile Picture");
    // const [fileName, setFileName] = useState("Upload CV");
  
    return (
        <form autoComplete="off" noValidate className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            
            <TextField
            id="name"
            name="name"
            className="name"
            label="Full Name"
            variant="outlined"
            value={postData.profile.name}
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, name: e.target.value })}
            />

            <TextField
            id="outlined-multiline-static"
            label="Multiline"
            multiline
            rows={4}
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            className="mb-3"
            name="description"
            value={postData.profile.description}
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, description: e.target.value })}
            fullWidth
            />

            <TextField
            id="email"
            label="Email"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            className="mb-3"
            name="email"
            value={postData.profile.email} 
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, email: e.target.value })}
            />
            <TextField
            id="phone"
            label="Phone Number"
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            name="phone"
            value={postData.profile.number}
            onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, number: e.target.value })}
            />
            <Button variant="light" type="submit" className="Save">Save</Button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default Profile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd look at the `name` field for example, you can see the value is `postData.profile.name` while `onChange` your setting `postData.name`.

Try setting the profile object, for example:

```
onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, profile: { ...postData.profile, name: e.target.value } })}
```

Comment: Hi, I was able to type but after typing 3-4 letters the value will back on the original value.

Comment: I think I see the problem. In devtools network tab I see that the api get method is being called infinitely.